# ognl 'in' statement not functioning as expected

Tags: java, struts2, ognl

I have the following code:

```
<s:iterator value="primaryDataSources" var="includedPrimaryDataSource">
    <s:property value="%{includedPrimaryDataSource in primaryDataSources}"/>
</s:iterator>
```

with primaryDataSources being an ArrayList initialised in my action class:

```
List<String> primaryDataSources = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"SE", "QBP", "Olympic", "J&B"}));
```

When I output primaryDataSources on its own like this:

```
 <s:property value="%{primaryDataSources}"/>
```

it outputs [SE, QBP, Olympic, J&B]

I would expect that the 'in' ognl statement would always return true, however it is always false... Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `#` to reference your `includedPrimaryDataSource`, also `%{...}` is not needed inside `<s:property>` tag.

```
<s:iterator value="primaryDataSources" var="includedPrimaryDataSource">
    <s:property value="#includedPrimaryDataSource in primaryDataSources"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Thanks this works! I will accept as soon as Stack Overflow lets me... It's a little confusing because I can output <s:property value="%{includedPrimaryDataSource"}/> without a problem...